# Unshifting destructively an array into an array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, memory

Say I have two sizable arrays, `a` and `b`.

I want to have `b=a+b`, but I don't really need `a` afterwards, and would much rather have the memory saved, in order to avoid swapping.

I have thought about simply using:

```
b.unshift( *a.slice!(0..-1) )
```

But the above has the downside of still keeping a copy of `a` until the procedure is finished. The other option would be:

```
while ! a.empty?() do 
       b.unshift( a.pop() )
end
```

While not elegant, and maybe even slower (this is iterations, I don't know how fast the `*` operator works, maybe it is on lower level), this keeps the intermediate memory footprint to a minimum.

Is there something more elegant?

Comment: What about `b = a.concat(b)`?

Comment: How do you know that ruby won't allocate N copies of `a` (and thus waste this memory) while you add elements one by one? If you _do_ care about memory, you need to memory-profile the code and see how much objects does each variant allocate.

Comment: @Stefan then it would be `b = a.concat(b); a = []` which is the same as `b.unshift(*a); a = []`. I believe that's not quite what @user1134991 asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something more elegant?

Using both `unshift` and `pop`:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]

b.unshift(*a.pop(a.size))

p a, b
# []
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Or if you don't want to use `*`:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]

b.unshift(a.pop(a.size)).flatten!

p a, b
# []
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: This probably creates a lot more garbage than the original attempt, so be aware.

Comment: @tadman "*probably*"? You don't quite understand how this works, do you? Here, let me explain it for you. `a.pop(a.size)` will return entire array `a` and will also remove all elements from array `a`. What's been happening to memory is determined by implementation of Ruby. Both variants described in the answer completely free memory for array `a` when using default Ruby.

Comment: That's "probably" not the way you should explain something to anyone, especially not someone who's answered thousands of questions about Ruby. I say probably only because different implementations, even different versions of Ruby have variations on how this is handled, but this is by no means a guaranteed "better" solution.

Comment: @tadman if you are so experienced in "answering *thousands* of questions about Ruby", then you should have tested my solutions before saying that “this ... creates *a lot more* garbage than the original attempt ...”. By doing so, you would have known that it’s not true. Moreover, the way this is handled is being unchanged from at least Ruby 1.9.3 up to current version.

Comment: Memory-profiling these snippets and those of OP would help in persuading audience that this sometimes does perform better. At a glance, both these snippets allocate at least one new array of `a.size`. About the same as the code in the question.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev agreed. I found first comment left by Mr. @tadman inappropriate because it said that my code performs worse than the original, but in fact it doesn’t. No analysis have been made before saying that. No doubt that Mr. @tadman is very experienced, but that comment was unprofessional. Note that I have never said that I deny the fact that `b += a` would perform better on memory. My answer to the question “Is there something more elegant?” begins with words “Using both `unshift` and `pop` ...”.

Comment: took the liberty of including the exact question you were responding to.

Comment: @MOPO3OB I made that observation because I had a sneaking suspicion this might be a step backwards. You're welcome to challenge that, but verbally berating someone for simply having skepticism is really out of line. I've addressed performance-related queries before and sometimes the fastest thing is very surprising because of Ruby's internal optimizations. The problem I have with this solution is it *incrementally* extends the target array which may result in several increasingly large allocations. A concatenation operation can allocate the new size once.

Comment: @tadman why do you say that it extends the target array *incrementally*?

Comment: That's what `unshift` does, it adds one element at a time. If you were doing this on an array of length 1e6 that would require multiple extensions to that array's size, each one of which is a new allocation + copy of existing data (pointers). Most dynamic arrays resize by increments of 1.5-2x. That means going from length 0 to length 1,000,000 requires about 19-39 allocations.

Comment: @tadman does it? Doesn't `ary_memcpy0(ary, 0, argc, argv, target_ary); ARY_SET_LEN(ary, len + argc);` do that in one step?

Comment: I'm asking how the initial `unshift` operation has enough context for Ruby to know that this is the first of a million unshifts you're about to perform. Obviously it doesn't, so it just extends the array incrementally using the usual rules. When doing a concat it knows exactly how long the new array has to be, so yeah, then it *can* extend in one shot.

Comment: I think both `concat` and `unshift` know how long the new array would be. They both use `RARRAY_LEN()` for calculating that.

Answer (score 2):

There's no guarantee the memory allocated to `a` will be released just because you've removed all of the elements. Most dynamic array systems allocate as the array is increased in size, that's a hard necessity, but are more relaxed when it comes to decreasing size.

The best approach is to do `b += a`, let `a` fall out of scope, and then let the garbage collector sort it out.

Unless you can produce a concrete benchmark that shows that your convoluted approach works better, which it probably doesn't as a splat operation is going to create additional garbage that needs to be collected, you should do the simplest thing that works.

Comment: There were times when MRI would not release any memory at all (its heap would only grow, never shrink). I think it's better now. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ah, the 1.8 days where we had to processes out back and shoot them because they'd become too fat and old.

Comment: Was it only up to 1.8? My memory is fuzzy, but I'm quite sure that 1.9 was also behaving like this.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev 1.8 was so bad that "Enterprise Ruby" existed to fix the problem. 1.9 made big improvements, 2.0 largely better.